# Packaging Java/Netbeans project for easy end user usage

Tags: java, netbeans

(I guess this is less a question than a report/personal experience looking for critique or whatever. The project described contains an external library.)

Many users need *more* than all the help they can get in trying to execute a Java project. I'm describing ways that come to mind for getting a project to a user--none particularly foolproof--and wonder if I'm missing some much-easier method.

One way: Do what the dist folder README says: "To distribute this project, right click to **zip up the dist folder** (including the lib folder) and distribute the ZIP file" and, I'll add, hope the user has the skill to extract and then find the executable jar. And to go get a JRE if need be.

A seamless way: use Netbeans **7.4** *Native Java Packaging*, which produces a **self-extracting executable** (an "EXE installer"; an .EXE file) and runs whether or not user has JRE installed. It can be executed from Windows Search box (and can be uninstalled via Control Panel). Method assumes NO JRE available; *humongous* (**30MB**) .EXE was produced. [See [((this link))](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2013/11/native-java-packaging-with-netbeans-74.html)

Unhappy medium: forget the admirable use of an external library; just **add the package** containing the library's source code. This produces a .jar that runs if JRE is present; otherwise user still has to get involved.

None of the above are exactly ideal ways of providing an app for a tech-challenged user.

I was going to include **Webstart** as a fourth and what I hoped best alternative, but for no apparent reason, I can't get a compilation that works inside my own Netbeans IDE. Calls to the utility modules--now included in the GUI part of the project; external in NO WAY--never pop up the dialogs they should.

Comment: There's not likely to a "single" solution.  Embedding the JRE seems to be the way things are moving (Apple now requires Java based App bundles to embed the JRE).  There are some installers available that will either embed a selected JRE or download it as part of their installation process.  When you add in the fact that "Windows" isn't the only available client target, you start getting yourself in a real tither.

Comment: There's always [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/). A happy medium - executable that downloads a jvm if necessary.